# How to synchronize cursor movement in multiple split windows?

Tags: vim

I remember Notepad++ has this feature, which is really helpful to compare files. I want to realize the similar one in Vim. When moving cursor in one split, cursors in the other split windows will move automatically.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Depending on what you're after, I see 2 possibilities.

---

**1) Diffing windows**

If you want to compare files, have a look at `:help diff`. E.g.

*You're on the shell:*

`$ vimdiff file1 file2` or `$ vim -d file1 file2`

*You have one window open already*:

`:vertical diffsplit foo.c`

*You have 2 windows open already*:

Do `:diffthis` in each of them.

---

**2) Scrollbinding windows**

You might also like `:help 'scrollbind'` and `:help scroll-binding`, if you don't want to jump into diff mode. Thus in the easiest case it's only doing `:set scrollbind` in both windows.

Comment: To simplify the response. The commands are ":set scb" (start scrollbinding) and ":set noscb" (stop scrollbinding)

Comment: @HMK I wasn't 100% certain what you're after, so I edited the answer to tell about diffing *and* scrollbinding.

Comment: While this is certainly correct, I think, one should also mention that  there is also the 'cursorbind' setting and the 'scrollopt' setting.

Comment: Although I read `scroll-binding` myself, I somehow managed to always overread the existince of `'cursorbind'`. Thanks for mentioning

Comment: `cursorbind` is what I was looking for!